# What is the Replacement for props.data?

Tags: typescript, jsx, deno, freshjs

I am currently building a personal website using Deno's Fresh.js. I need to pass the contents of a text file into a dynamic route page, and I am following the documentation on the Fresh website, which instructs to use `props.data`. However, in my IDE (Visual Studio Code), it says that the `data` attribute for props is deprecated, and that values should be passed to state. Using `data.props` currently works without issue, but I would like to know what the preferred method for passing data is if Fresh's `props.data` is deprecated, and I cannot find any information on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the response to the issue posted on the Github, the feature in question was deprecated too early, and has been undeprecated in 1.6.1.